# How to merge multiple objects into one and deal with duplicate keys in typescript

Tags: angular, algorithm, typescript

I am working with ng2-charts and i need to populate a horizontal bar chart.
I am getting my values inside a keys.forEach and the resulting console.log for my chart data is (example):

```
{ReasonA: 5}
{ReasonA: 5, ReasonB: 5}
{ReasonA: 1, ReasonB: 3, ReasonC: 2}
{ReasonA: 1, ReasonB: 4, ReasonE: 2}
```

I need to combine the objects into one, and deal with multiple values for the same key. The **desired result** for this example would be this object:

```
{ReasonA: 12, ReasonB: 12, ReasonC: 2, ReasonE: 2}
```

With that object then i could split the keys and values and populate de chart. Can you guide me into **how can i merge the 4 objects into the desired result**?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all the properties are numbers it is pretty simple logic using an array `reduce`. If the properties have different types then the logic will be slightly more complex. Here is an example of a function you could write to achieve this:

```js
function sumProperties(...objects: { [key: string]: number }[]) {
  return objects.reduce((acc, obj) => {
    for (let key in obj) {
      let a = acc[key] || 0;
      let b = obj[key];
      acc[key] = a + b;
    }

    return acc;
  }, {});
}
```

Example Use:

```
sumProperties(
  {ReasonA: 5},
  {ReasonA: 5, ReasonB: 5},
  {ReasonA: 1, ReasonB: 3, ReasonC: 2},
  {ReasonA: 1, ReasonB: 4, ReasonE: 2},
)
```

Comment: Thanks, I managed to try your function and it serves as purpose. Just need to adapt it to my code.

Comment: I just need to merge/concatenate all the objects into one array. Desired intermediate  output is: [{ReasonA: 5}, {ReasonA: 5, ReasonB: 5}, {ReasonA: 1, ReasonB: 3, ReasonC: 2}, {ReasonA: 1, ReasonB: 4, ReasonE: 2}]

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the solution Teddy

Answer (score 2):

you can also use `forEach` and `Object.keys` for getting each object key and check, if it exists in `result` object, if it is, then plus value, if not then assign new value

```js
const toOneObject = (...objects) => {
  const result = {};
  objects.forEach(obj => Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => result[k] ? result[k] += obj[k] : result[k] = obj[k]));
  return result;
}

console.log(toOneObject(
  {ReasonA: 5},
  {ReasonA: 5, ReasonB: 5},
  {ReasonA: 1, ReasonB: 3, ReasonC: 2},
  {ReasonA: 1, ReasonB: 4, ReasonE: 2}
));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use lodash, you can use `_.extendWith` to achieve less code :)

```
_.extendWith({ReasonA: 5},
             {ReasonA: 5, ReasonB: 5},
             {ReasonA: 1, ReasonB: 3, ReasonC: 2},
             {ReasonA: 1, ReasonB: 4, ReasonE: 2}, 
             (obj, src) => (obj||0) + (src||0))
```